# Converting DateTime to EPOCH time is returning a new Date

Tags: c#, datetime, highcharts, epoch

To convert date time to EPOCH time , I am using following function:

```
public static long EpochTime(DateTime dt)
        {
            //long form code to be clear
            TimeSpan t = dt.ToLocalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            long millisecondsSinceEpoch = (long)t.TotalSeconds * 1000;
            return millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        }
```

Now If I test the function with input date as , `15/07/2018 1:09:42 PM`, the out put date becomes ,

> GMT: Sunday, July 15, 2018 11:09:42 PM
>   Your time zone: Monday, July 16, 2018 9:09:42 AM GMT+10:00

I need the epoch time as Highchart needs epoch time on x-axis.

Comment: You can set timezone in highcharts if that helps: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time

Comment: Why the down vote??

Comment: Why are you calling `ToLocalTime`? That's the opposite of what you want in almost all cases.

Comment: try DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()

Comment: @DaisyShipton,@Marco Salerno ,@ewolden Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you're comparing times in the correct timezones. I recommend converting both to UTC:

```
TimeSpan t = dt.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```